# O que tem de errado com a lógica desse código ´Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, booleano

```
x = bool(input("True or False...? "))
if x == 'True':
    print("Você escollheu True")
else:
    print("Você escolheu False")
```

O que tem de errado com essa lógica, mais especificamente sobre a lógica envolvendo a variável booleana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem dois problemas na lógica. Primeiro a função [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) não pode transformar a *string* em um valor booleano como espera, então a comparação correta é com *string*, mas sem a função. Segundo que se a pessoa não digitar `True`, não tem como saber se ela digitou `False` sem testar especificamente por isso.

```
x = input("True ou False...? ")
if x == 'True':
    print("Você escolheu True")
else:
    print("Você não escolheu True")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/K1v5vS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jeevbnly-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TrueFalse.py).

Ou

```
x = input("True ou False...? ")
if x == 'True':
    print("Você escolheu True")
elif x == 'False':
    print("Você escolheu False")
else:
    print("Você não escolheu True ou False")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mx5EE3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gjpwubnr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TrueFalse2.py).

Ou ainda pode aceitar digitação ignorando maiúsculas:

```
x = input("True ou False...? ").lower()
if x == 'true':
    print("Você escolheu True")
elif x == 'false':
    print("Você escolheu False")
else:
    print("Você não escolheu True ou False")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eLYHbI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gwjlynbb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TrueFalse3.py).

Se ainda quiser a função `bool()` tem que entender que uma *string* falsa é quando ela é vazia:

```
x = bool(input("Digite alguma coisa ou deixe em branco...? "))
if x: #não precisa usar True porque é isto que o if espera
    print("Você digitou algo")
else:
    print("Você não digitou algo")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1zzDQl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pxuchpah-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/TrueFalse4.py).